# UIAlertView delegate meethod is not calling?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, uialertview

When i receive push notification iam calling this method inside appDelegate

```
-(void)activeNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{
    NSLog(@"%@",userInfo);
    NSString *message = [[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"alert"];


    ViewController *view=[[ViewController alloc]init];
    [view checkNotification:message];
}
```

From here am calling a method `checkNotification:message()` defined in ViewController.m

```
-(void)checkNotification:(NSString *)message{
        NSLog(@"%@",message);
        NSArray *arr=[[NSArray alloc]init];

    if([message hasPrefix:@"taxi"])
    {
        arr=[message componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];

        alertV=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Taxi" message:[arr objectAtIndex:1] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alertV show];

    }
 }
```

And when i click Ok button i need to call alertview delegate method

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
}
```

but this method is not getting called please help me

In my ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<FBLoginViewDelegate,UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

I dont know why AlertView delegate is not called ..

Comment: In your app delegate you are allocating a new view controller instance.  You probably want to invoke the method on the instance that is already on screen

Comment: please tell me clearly..i didnt understand anything

Comment: i can see alertview on my app screen Only problem is when i click "ok" button  that delegate method is not working

Comment: When you say ` ViewController *view=[[ViewController alloc]init];` you are creating a new instance of the ViewController - this is not the instance that is managing your display

Comment: so then how do i call my method?

Comment: If you only have one view controller then your app delegates `rootViewController` is probably your `ViewController` instance, but if your view controller is embedded in a navigation controller or similar then you will need to work through the view hierarchy.  You can also decouple by sending a message via NSNotificationCenter

Comment: my ViewController is connected to uinavigationcontroller.  can u please show some example codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is allocating a new instance of `ViewController`, but you need to get a reference to the actual view controller that is in your view hierarchy.

You said that your `ViewController` is in a UINavigationController, so assuming that it is the first view controller that you display, it will be at the root of the navigation stack.  You can get a reference to it using the following code -

```
-(void)activeNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{
    NSLog(@"%@",userInfo);
    NSString *message = [[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"alert"];

    UINavigationController *navC=(UINavigationController *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;

    ViewController *view=navC.viewControllers[0];
    [view checkNotification:message];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple problems. As @Robse says, you are creating a new view controller instance in your app delegate that isn't connecting to anything and trying to invoke a method in that instance. That doesn't make any sense, and it's hard to tell you how to fix it without knowing more about your app.

You need a way to get to the current front view controller and display the alert on that view controller. In order to help you with that you're going to have to explain how you create and display view controllers in your app. Are you using storyboards? Can you be certain of which view controller is being displayed when you receive the push notification?

Ok, based on your comments, I'm guessing that your view controller is being loaded by your app's main storyboard, and is the initial view controller for your app. That's the view controller that gets loaded automatically on launch.

To get access to the root view controller of the app's main window, use code like this:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController
```

So, your code would look like this:

```
-(void)activeNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{
NSLog(@"%@",userInfo);
  NSString *message = [[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"alert"];

  ViewController *rootVC;
  rootVC = (ViewController *) [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
  [rootVC checkNotification:message];
}
```

That code asks the application for the app's key window, then asks the key window for it's root view controller, which in your case should be your app's starting view controller

Edit: Nevermind. I see from your newer comments that your default view controller is NOT your view controller but that you have a navigation controller. In that case you should use Paulw11's code instead.

When you post a question, please try to provide a complete description of your problem.

The following would have been a much, MUCH better description of your problem:

> I have an app that uses storyboards." The initial view controller is a
>   navigation controller, and then the root view controller of the
>   navigation controller is an instance of my ViewController class. I'm
>   trying to send a message to my ViewController when the app delegate
>   receives a push notification.

With that we would have been able to answer your question in one shot.

Note that often, thinking through how to describe your problem clearly and completely enough for somebody else to help solve it will trigger you to find your problem on your own.

Comment: yes am using storyboard..am using default ViewController  .thats my Home page

Answer (score -1):

The Problem is, you are giving the wrong delegate. Your delegate is a temporary ViewController crated in the AppDelegate. It will destroyed as soon as the method activeNotification:(NSDictionary *) returns. But you will click the button at a later time. You have to ensure, the lifetime of the delegate.

You could also use another delegate, like directly the AppDelegate or the RootViewController.

As Paulw11 pointed out, the below wouldn't work because a new instance is returned from the method instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:(NSString *):

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                                     bundle: nil];
MyViewController *controller = (MyViewController*)[mainStoryboard 
                instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"<Controller ID>"];
```

Comment: This does the same thing that the OP is doing, just using a storyboard - you still end up with a new instance.  They may be able to use the `rootViewController` property of their appDelegate

Comment: In order for your code to work you'd have to display the newly instantiated view controller somehow (present it modally, or push it onto a navigation stack. If you don't it will have the same problem you describe (going away as soon as your code returns) as @PaulW mentions.